# Are the following interpretations of EViews output correct?

Tags: regression, interpretation, descriptive-statistics, eviews

I just wanted to know if my interpretation of the follow values were right:

- **Std. error (of each independent variable):** Indicates the likely sample variability (and hence reliability). Estimated coefficients +- 2 std error is the 95% confidence interval.
- **t-Statistic:** Determines whether or not an independent variable is irrelevant to the regression (i.e. the coefficient is 0). Absolute t-stat values of 2 or more mean the 95% confidence interval of the coefficient does not include the value 0; But the greater the absolute value, the better.
- **p-value of t-Stat** The probability that the absolute value of the actual t-Stat is greater than the estimated t-Stat. No magic cut-off, but values less than 0.1 are viewed as strong evidence against irrelevance, while values less than 0.05 are viewed as very strong evidence against irrelevance. The lower the better.
- **Sum of Squared Residuals (SSR):** All the squared values of the residuals when using the estimated coefficients. The minimized value is output in EViews and has no direct use, but is used as inputs in other diagnostics and used to compare between models. When comparing models, lower SSR is preferred.
- **Log-Likelihood:** The value which maximized the log-likelihood function. When disturbances in the regression are normally distributed, maximizing the log-likelihood is the same as minimizing the SSR. You want the value to be as great as possible.
- **F-Statistic:** Determines whether or not all the independent variables are jointly irrelevant to the regression (i.e. the coefficients are all 0). If none of the variables have predictive value, the F-Statistic follows an F distribution with k-1 and T-k degrees of freedom. You want the EViews output value as much as possible because it means something is significant? (not sure)
- **p-value of F-Stat:** The probability that... (not sure how to describe this).
- **S.E. of Regression:** Measures the disturbance of the error term in the regression. You want this to be as small as possible because large values means the model didn't fit well to the dependent variable. SE of regression should not be above 10% or 15% of the mean of the dependent variable
- **R-squared and Adjust r-squared:** Measured the in-sample success of the regression equation in forecasting the dependent variable. Used to determine "goodness of fit". You want the R-squared to be as close to 1 as possible, but above 0.5 is alright. The Adjusted R-squared is similar but accounts for the number of regressors (so for # of regressors > 1, it will be smaller that R-squared
- **Akaike Info Criterion (AIC) and Schwarz criterion (SIC):** AIC is used to estimate the out-of-sample forecast error variance, like the Standard Error of the regression, but penalizes degrees of freedom more harshly. SIC is an alternative to AIC, which penalizes degrees of freedom even more harshly. You want both of these to be low and you pick the model with the lower values, but if you just have 1 model are these criteria useless? (i.e. is there a cut-off value for these?)
- **Durbin-Watson stat:** Tests for serial correlation in the error term of the regression. If there is serial correlation, then we can improve the forecast by forecasting the forecast errors. The DW stat lies between 0 and 4. When DW approaches 0 there is positive autocorrelation, whilst approaching 4, there is negative autocorrelation. According to the textbook the acceptable zone is 1.5-2, but what about between 2-2.5? I think they didn't mention values above 2 because we won't encounter values about 2 in this course maybe.
- **Jarque-Bera test:** Tests whether the distribution of the sample is normal. You want the JB value to be as low as possibleI keep remembering the tutor saying you want this to be 5.99 (or maybe 6) or something, but I can't find anything about it online about when you reject normality for this. Is the number 6 important for this test or am I mixing it with something else (because I'm fairly sure 6 is important some where).

I'm really interested in these statistics/tests and want to make sure I'm not misinterpreting them. For some of them I'm confident I understand them, but I'm not so sure (JB test, DW-stat, F-stat and it's p-value, SSR and the log-likelihood). (All of these except the JB are in EViews output and I'm trying toexplaining them in the context of a linear regression)